# What's this variables without value

Tags: php, syntax

I saw this on some code:

```
if(intval($id)!==){//some code}
```

What's `!==` meaning without no value

Comment: a syntax error     :)

Comment: that simply means ERROR

Comment: Will yield a "*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in*" -- See for yourselfe https://3v4l.org/ugcr1

Answer (score 0):

This peace of code results in a PHP Parse error. I tested it on PHP 7.2, I don't think there's any PHP version supporting this syntax.

[image: PHP syntax error]

Answer (score 0):

The expression have an error because is expecting a value to compare to.

You are using the `!==` comparison operator but you are not comparing it to nothing, for hence the syntax error.

In the other hand if you want to get if the value is false or 0 by using loose type you can do it like:

```
if(!$id){
 // code
}
```

But if you want to avoid error in comparison because of the loose type you should do it like:

```
if($val !== 1){
/// code
}
```

In your canse you are getting the int value of the variable and doing a comparison of type and value of the variable but it does not have to comparison to be made and that's why you get the syntax error. you should add a comparison value so you can compare it to something.

```
if(intval($id)!== 0){
    //code
}
```

[PHP Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
function get_post_by_id($id=null){
    if(!empty($id) && intval($id)!==){       
    $result=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_ID={$id} LIMIT 1");
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
}
```